# Add space between number and letter in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to make a formula that adds space between numbers and letters, but it's not working, some strings it adds the space and others don't. Can anyone help me out and explain where I'm going wrong, seeing that some of it additional could be the format? Or if there is any way I can use a VBA UserDefined Function to get the intended result

My current formula:

```
=TRIM(REPLACE(B3;MAX(IFERROR(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};B3;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B3))));0))+1;0;" "))
```

Edit: The numbers will not always be accompanied by A and B, it can be any letter from A to Z

[image: Example]

Comment: Will the letters always follow the numbers? or could some cells have content like `AB12`? or `AB12CD` or `12AB34`?

Comment: Always Number then Letter

Comment: Wait, what is your delimiter when wanting a horizontal array.  In the US it is `{A,B}` the array `{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9}` must be horizontal, which is why for me using `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` works.

Comment: I think you want `{0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9}` and be sure to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: Your original formula is volatile - due to use of `INDIRECT()` - you can remedy this by replacing the `ROW()` function with this version: `ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A;LEN(B3)))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Assumptions***

- Numeric sequences come first
- No numeric sequences start with a zero (0)
- No more than five (5) digits in the numeric sequence

  - (Adjust the array constant if there are more than 5)

This formula detects the maximum value of the number portion, and then splits that off.

```
=MAX(IFERROR(--MID(A1,1,{1,2,3,4,5}),0)) & SUBSTITUTE(A1,MAX(IFERROR(--MID(A1,1,{1,2,3,4,5}),0))," ")
```

If the first digit might be a zero (0), you can use this longer formula which detects the position of the first letter.

```
=LEFT(A1,MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH({"A";"B";"C";"D";"E";"F";"G";"H";"I";"J";"K";"L";"M";"N";"O";"P";"Q";"R";"S";"T";"U";"V";"W";"X";"Y";"Z"},A1),0))-1) & " " & MID(A1,MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH({"A";"B";"C";"D";"E";"F";"G";"H";"I";"J";"K";"L";"M";"N";"O";"P";"Q";"R";"S";"T";"U";"V";"W";"X";"Y";"Z"},A1),0)),LEN(A1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With Office 365 Dynamic arrays:

```
=REDUCE("",MID(B3,SEQUENCE(LEN(B3)),1),LAMBDA(a,b,IF(AND(ISNUMBER(--a),ISERROR(--b)),a&" "&b,a&b)))
```

NOTE: This assumes the text is always in the order of numbers then letters.

[image]

---

Note: for older versions the formula used by the OP in their question works.  It just needs to be confirmed with `Ctrl`-`Shift`-`Enter` instead of `Enter` when exiting edit mode:

[image]

Comment: Im on Home and Business 2019, how can i recreate this formula?

Comment: Then your formula works, But you would need to confirm it with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter to make it an array formula.

Comment: But i dont have REDUCE or SEQUENCE, how can i recreate? And did some edit on my question, sorry about the incovenience

Comment: No, your formula that you provided in the question works.  You just need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: I will try switching for the english version then. I tried here but didnt work maybe its cuz im on Portuguese versios

Comment: see my comment above.  I think the issue is that your array `{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9}` is vertical and it needs to be horizontal.  not sure what delimiter you would use for that.

Comment: The delimiter for the array is ";" , if i use "," i get error

Comment: I think you want `{0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9}` and be sure to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Answer (score 3):

What about this, assuming O365. It spills the entire array, no need to drag the formula down:

```
=LET(in,A1:A3, after,TEXTAFTER(in,CHAR(ROW(48:57)),-1), 
 before,SUBSTITUTE(in,after,""), before &" "& after)
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

`after` gets the substring after the last digit (`-1`, reverse search), `before`, the substring with the digits, then just to concatenate both arrays adding a space in the middle. `CHAR(ROW(48:57))` represents all the digits to find: `0-9`, but you can use: `SEQUENCE(10,,0)` for the same purpose.

Answer (score 2):

```
=LET(a,A1,
     x,XMATCH(1,--ISERROR(--(MID(a,SEQUENCE(LEN(a)),1)))),
LEFT(a,x-1)&" "&MID(a,x,LEN(a)))
```

Where `a` is the cell you want to add the space-character in between the number and the text.
`x` finds the first character to error if the characters are converted to number character by character.
(Converting a character to a number throws an error)

Then the cell characters prior to the found position is followed by `" "` and the remaining characters.

Edit:
I read you don't have sequence and reduce, so this will work in older Excel:

```
=LEFT(A1,
      MATCH(1,
            --ISERROR(--MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1))),1)),
            0)
            -1)
      &" "&
      MID(A1,
          MATCH(1,
                --ISERROR(--MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1))),1)),0),
          LEN(A1))
```

I think it requires being entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`

PS, you own formula seems to work as is. Make sure to also use `ctrl+shift+enter`